# How can I check the start of a string with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I currently have:

```
if ($(this).data('action') == "Editing" || $(this).data('action') == "Create") {
    tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEOptions);
}
```

What I need to do is to check for "Create Menu" or "Create Referene". Basically any data starting with the word "Create".

How can I do this with a wildcard?

Comment: Are these HTML5 data attributes or cached data accessed through jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are attributes of the element (as far as we know, it's `this`), then you can use this:

```
if( $(this).is("[data-action^='Create']") ){
    tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEOptions);
}
```

`$(this).is("[data-action^='Create']")` will check if the `data-action` attribute of the returned element(s) *starts with* the string `Create`. It will return `true` or `false`. We're using the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Change `$(this).is("[data-action^='Create']")` to `$(this).is("[data-action^='Editing']")`.

Comment: @SamanthaJ `if( $(this).is("[data-action^='Create']") || $(this).is("[data-action^='Edit']") ){
    tinyMCE.init(window.tinyMCEOptions);
}`

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "Create Menu";  

/^Create/.test(s); // true
```

Update:

```
if($(this).data('action') == "Editing" || /^Create/.test($(this).data('action'))){
}
```

Comment: but how can I fit that in the jquery above?

Comment: @SamanthaJ I thought you would know that ... alright, I will add it

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old now, but I thought it might be worthwhile adding that a check like this could also work:

```
var s = "Create Menu";
if (s.indexOf("Create") === 0) { // 0 is the start position of the string
    console.log("string begins with Create");
}
```