# How can I check string  starts with using javascript / jQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the start of a string with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425533/how-can-i-check-the-start-of-a-string-with-jquery)

I have the following:

```
if ($(this).data('action') == "Editing" || $(this).data('action') == "Create") 
{
  // how to Check  ? 
}
```

How can I check for where Editing or Create are just the first words and not the complete string?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [indexOf method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check that the first occurrence is at the start of the string:

```
$(this).data('action').indexOf("Editing") == 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using a regular expression, like so:

```
 var action = $(this).data('action');
 var regex = /^(Editing|Create)/i;
 if (regex.test(action)) {
      // do something
 }
```

Comment: Whouldn't it be `/^(Editing|Create)/.test(action)`?

Comment: @elclanrs So it should. I always mix the order up. I'm surprised I got five votes before someone realised, though! Fixed.

Comment: yeah, I always think twice about the order. JS and its oddities...

Answer (score 2):

You could use substring() or a Regex (i'd use substring which is easier to read)

```
if ($(this).data('action').substring(0, 7) == "Editing" || $(this).data('action').substring(0, 6) == "Create")
```

Comment: lol, maybe a fast way. Buuut... very hard coded ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's `substr` method (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

```
if ($(this).data('action').substr(0, 7) == "Editing" || $(this).data('action').substr(0, 6) == "Create") {
```